# How to merge a list with a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, concatenation, sublist

How to merge two lists (one a list of lists) in Python?

Input:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]

B = [0,1,1,1]
```

Desired output:

```
C = [[[1,2,3],[0]],[[1,2,3],[1]],[[1,2,3],[1]],[[1,2,3],[1]]]
```

I tried:

```
zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have answers to achieve this using *list comprehension*. You may achieve it with `zip()` as well, if you use it in right way as:

- using `map(zip())` combination as:

  ```
  >>> list(map(lambda x: [A[0], [x]], B))
  [[[1, 2, 3], [0]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]]]
  ```
- using `zip(map())` combination as:

  ```
  >>> zip([A[0]]*4, map(lambda x: [x], B))
  [([1, 2, 3], [0]), ([1, 2, 3], [1]), ([1, 2, 3], [1]), ([1, 2, 3], [1])]
  ```

  *Explanation:* Here `map()` will convert your list `B` to:

  ```
  >>> map(lambda x: [x], B)
  [[0], [1], [1], [1]]
  ```

  and `[A[0]]*4` will create new list with copies of `A[0]` as:

  ```
  >>> [A[0]]*4
  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
  ```

  Now you need to just `zip()` the both lists.

`

Answer (score 1):

According to your expected output, you are trying to combine the first inner list from list `A` with each item from list `B`.
Use the following simple approach(*list comprehension*):

```
C = [[A[0], [i]] for i in B]

print(C)
```

The output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [0]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way of doing it

```
A=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]

B=[0,1,1,1]

map(lambda e: [A[0],[e]], B)
```

Output ::

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [0]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]], [[1, 2, 3], [1]]]
```

Comment: yup made the required changes...now it looks good i guess...can someone accept this answer if yes